# OrientDB ETL edge lookup from query - how to access $input?

Tags: graph, etl, orientdb

I'm trying my darnedest to do an ETL import from a large dataset that I've been keeping in MongoDB. I've successfully imported the vertices, and I feel like I'm one little syntax misunderstanding away from importing the edges too.

I am pretty sure that the error is in this transformer:

```
{"edge":{"class":"Friend", "joinFieldName":"id", 
  "lookup": "select from Character WHERE $input.id IN character_friends",
  "unresolvedLinkAction":"CREATE"}},
```

So what I'm trying to do is to make an edge from a document with id = FOO to all other documents that contain FOO in their character_friends array.
If I execute

```
select from Character WHERE FOO IN character_friends
```

in the browser, I get a ton of documents, so my guess is that my problem is with $input.id either not returning the id I'm expecting, or maybe not being recognized as a variable at all.

Documents look like this:

```
{
  id: FOO,
  character_friends: [BAR, BAZ, QUX]
  (and a bunch of other junk)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're inserting a property "id", but it's reserved in Blueprints standard. You can rename it (with "field" transformers) or set this in Orient Loader:

```
  standardElementConstraints: false,
```

Then I've created the file /temp/datasets/charles.json with this content:

```
[
 {
  name: "Joe",
  id: 1,
  friends: [2,4,5],
  enemies: [6]
 },
 {
  name: "Suzie",
  id: 2,
  friends: [1,4,6],
  enemies: [5,2]
 }
]
```

And this pipeline:

```
{
  config: {
    log: "debug",
    parallel: false
  },
  source : {
    file: { path: "/temp/datasets/charles.json", lock : true }
  },
  extractor : {
    json: {}
  },
  transformers : [
    { merge: { joinFieldName:"id", lookup:"Account.id" } },
    { vertex: { class: "Account"} },
    { edge: {
      "class": "Friend",
      "joinFieldName": "friends",
      "lookup": "Account.id",
      "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
    } },
    { edge: {
      "class": "Enemy",
      "joinFieldName": "enemies",
      "lookup": "Account.id",
      "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
    } }
  ],
  loader : {
    orientdb: {
      dbURL: "plocal:/temp/databases/charles",
      dbUser: "admin",
      dbPassword: "admin",
      dbAutoDropIfExists: true,
      dbAutoCreate: true,
      standardElementConstraints: false,
      tx: false,
      wal: false,
      batchCommit: 1000,
      dbType: "graph",
      classes: [{name: 'Account', extends:"V"}, {name: 'Friend', extends:"E"}, {name: 'Enemy', extends:"E"}],
      indexes: [{class:"Account", fields:["id:integer"], type:"UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX" }]
    }
  }
}
```

Assure to use last version of ETL jar (replace it in $ORIENTDB/lib) with default version. Last version is downloadable from:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-etl/2.0.2-SNAPSHOT/orientdb-etl-2.0.2-20150208.225903-1.jar

Or get OrientDB ETL 2.0.2 of major.